# Image thresholding with SSE

Tags: c++, image-processing, x86, sse, simd

I'm trying to code an image segmentation code with SSE optimization. I have a strange result.
[image]

This is my code :

```
void binaire_sse(unsigned int * img, long h,long l, long seuil ,unsigned int * out)
{
    __m128i vThreshold = _mm_set1_epi8(seuil);
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < h; ++i)
    {
        const __m128i * p_in = (__m128i *)&img[i * l];
        uint16_t * p_out = (uint16_t *)&out[i * l / CHAR_BIT];

        for (j = 0; j < l; j += 16)
        {
            __m128i v = _mm_load_si128(p_in);
            uint16_t b;

            v = _mm_add_epi8(v, vThreshold);
            b = _mm_movemask_epi8(v); 
            *p_out = b;

            p_in++;
            p_out++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question provides too few details, but probably you should use `_mm_adds_epu8` instead of `_mm_add_epi8`

Comment: Thank for you comment. Well my question is how i can get a full thresholding image of picture on the left. you can see that i don't have the full image in my result(image in right). I tried your instruction but it does not change anything.

Comment: What is CHAR_BIT? Why +=16?

Comment: What is the pixel format? Is it RGB or grayscale? Is it 8-bits-per-component? Is it signed or unsigned? Also, the line `uint16_t * p_out = (uint16_t *)&out[i * l / CHAR_BIT];` seems suspicious.

Comment: the image is grayscale. 8_bits per component

Comment: Hi i'm trying another version of the code. But also i dont get what i wont.

Comment: __m128i sub_epi8 = _mm_set1_epi8(seuil);
for(int i=0; i<h*l; i+=16)
{
 __m128i chunk_epi8 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*) &img[i]);
 chunk_epi8 = _mm_sub_epi8(chunk_epi8, sub_epi8);
 chunk_epi8 = _mm_cmpgt_epi8(chunk_epi8, limit_epi8);
 _mm_store_si128((__m128i*) &out[i] ,chunk_epi8);
}

Comment: @BenChaabenAssil Then you have an error in initialization of `p_in` and `p_out`